# Hilbert subspaces of indefinite inner product spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, open-problems, banach-spaces

Let $E$ be a real linear space, endowed with a non-degenerate symmetric
bilinear form $(.,.)$.

Suppose that the [indefinite] inner product space $(E,(.,.))$
satisfies the following [sequential] properties:

(**WSC**) If the sequence { ${(x_{n},\ y)}$ } is Cauchy for each $y$ in $E$, then there
exists some $x$ in $E$ such that  $\left(x_{n}-x,y\right)$ $\rightarrow$ $0$
whenever $y$ in $E$.

(That is to say, $(E,(.,.))$ is *weakly sequentially complete*.)

and

(**DPG**) If $\left(x_{n},y\right)$ $\rightarrow$ $0$ for every $y$ in $E$,
then $\left(x_{n},x_{n}\right)$ $\rightarrow$ $0$.

(That would be sort of "*Dunford-Pettis & Grothendieck*'' property for indefinite inner product spaces.)

Suppose also that $|E|$ is "big enough'' (at least $|E|$ $>|\mathbb{R}|$).

**Conjecture**. $(E,(.,.))$ contains an infinite-dimensional Hilbert
subspace.

(That is, there exists a linear isometry from $(\ell^{2},<.,.>)$
into $(E,(.,.))$ .)

Comment: Presumably there are supposed to be commas somewhere in the properties listed above.

Comment: Indeed. Now it's OK ?


Comment: I'm curious - which condition fails if we take a Hilbert space with all norms multiplied by -1, or if we form an orthogonal direct sum of that with a positive definite copy of R?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't the Conjecture contradict (DPG)?

Comment: @Scott Carnahan The (DPG) fails.

Comment: @Mark Meckes No, because the infinite dimensional Hilbert subspace is not necessarily (and, due to (WSC), cannot be!) ortho-complemented in E.

Comment: I suppose less of what I know about bilinear forms on finite-dimensional spaces carries over to this context than I guessed.

Comment: @Ady: I don't understand your response to to Scott C, although I don't know much Hilbert space theory.  I would expect that (WSC,DPG) both hold for Hilbert spaces, but neither depends on $(,) \mapsto -(,)$, hence Scott's example.  On the other hand, if $(,)$ is negative-definite, then it certainly does not contain a (nontrivial) Hilbert space.

Comment: @Theo Johnson-Freyd All Hilbert spaces are (WSC), while no infinite-dimensional Hilbert space enjoys (DPG), since each orthonormal basis of any separable infinite-dimensional closed subspace is weakly converging to zero.

Comment: ...and thus it easily follows that all infinite dimensional Krein spaces are (WSC), but none of them has (DPG).


Comment: A quick question out of curiosity. What does it mean for a sequence to be Cauchy in one of these spaces? There is no norm or metric that I can see. But there is a uniform structure induced by the weak topology. Is that what is meant?

Comment: @Harald: I think so; certainly we can speak of weakly Cauchy sequences. However, what Ady is speaking of is a little different since we test only against elements of $E$ via the "pairing", rather than all of $E^*$

Comment: @Harald Hanche-Olsen Yes. (WSC) means that every weakly Cauchy sequence is weakly convergent, while (DPG) means
that the mapping x -> (x, x) is weakly sequentially continuous. Still, i didn't use the weak topology in their definitions.

Comment: @Yemon E with its weak topology is self-dual, i.e. every weakly continuous functional can
be (uniquely) expressed via the "pairing". And thus it can be viewed as an element of E.
